# How to leak memory in C# and .Net 7?

Tags: c#, .net-core, memory-leaks

Im trying to study "the art of reading memory dumps" and get bit better in finding memory leaks... in order to do that I thought that I would just write a code that leaks memory in the various fashion... problem is, im having a bit of hard time doing that...

so I wrote this simple api

```
public class LeakMemoryController : ControllerBase
{

    public const int MEGABYTE = 1048576;
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="managedMemory"></param>
    /// <param name="BigBlock"></param>
    /// <param name="amountMB"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    [HttpGet("/leak")]
    public async Task<MemoryReport> Leak(string managedOrUnamanagedMemory, string BigOrSmallBlock, int amountMB)
    {
        var rdn = Random.Shared;
        int buffSize;
        if (BigOrSmallBlock.ToLower() == "big")
        {
            buffSize = MEGABYTE / 2;
        }
        else
        {
            //10kb
            buffSize = 10240;
        }
        var iterations = (amountMB * MEGABYTE / buffSize) + 1;

        if (managedOrUnamanagedMemory.ToLower() == "unmanaged")
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < iterations; c++)
            {
                byte[] buff = new byte[buffSize];
                for (int i = 0; i < buff.Length; i++)
                {
                    buff[i] = (byte)rdn.Next(0, 255);
                }
                unsafe
                {
                    //Try number 1
                    var a = new IntPtr(&buff);                    
                }
                //try number 2
                Marshal.AllocHGlobal(buffSize);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            for (int c = 0; c < iterations; c++)
            {
                //todo: work later
            }
        }

        return await ReportMemory();
    }

    [HttpGet("/reportMemory")]
    public async Task<MemoryReport> ReportMemory()
    {
        var process = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
        process.Refresh();
        MemoryReport report = new MemoryReport();
        report.ProcessId = process.Id;
        report.NonpagedSystemMemorySize64 = process.NonpagedSystemMemorySize64;
        report.PagedSystemMemorySize64 = process.PagedSystemMemorySize64;
        report.PagedMemorySize64 = process.PagedMemorySize64;
        report.PrivateMemorySize64 = process.PrivateMemorySize64;
        report.VirtualMemorySize64 = process.VirtualMemorySize64 / MEGABYTE;
        report.WorkingSet64 = process.WorkingSet64 / MEGABYTE;

        process.Dispose();

        return report;
    }
}

public class MemoryReport
{
    public long NonpagedSystemMemorySize64 { get; set; }
    public long PagedSystemMemorySize64 { get; internal set; }
    public long PagedMemorySize64 { get; internal set; }
    public long PrivateMemorySize64 { get; internal set; }
    public long VirtualMemorySize64 { get; internal set; }
    public long WorkingSet64 { get; internal set; }
    public int ProcessId { get; internal set; }
}
```

but its not leaking... no matter how many times I call "Leak", the report is always around 60-75mb...

like, what am I doing wrong?

**Edit 1: Some evolution**
the code below crashes the debugger:

```
if (managedOrUnamanagedMemory.ToLower() == "unmanaged")
{
    for (int c = 0; c < iterations; c++)
    {
        IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(buffSize);
        unsafe
        {
            var span = new Span<byte>(&ptr, buffSize);
            for (int i = 0; i < span.Length; i++)
            {
                span[i] = (byte)rdn.Next(0, 255);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `no matter how many times I call "Leak"` - and are you passing "unmanaged" to it?

Comment: yes yes of course

Comment: [Here you go](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/debug-memory-leak)  This will give you some idea about how it all works with some code to show memory leak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, turns out that the code above does leak memory, the "problem" is that the memory doesn't stay resident (it gets paged) so the `dotnet counters` does not report it properly... if you check ActivityMonitor you will see the total memory process growing...

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the memory is not "commited" since it is not used. Windows tend to be sneaky and only map actual RAM to allocated addresses when they are actually used.

```
new Span<byte>(&ptr, buffSize);
```

I think this should be

```
new Span<byte>((byte*)ptr, buffSize);
```

If the goal is to get better at finding leaks, you need to understand how leaks happen in the first place. Most leaks are of managed memory and in managed code. Usually by adding something to a list that is never removed. A typical example is to repeatedly add event handlers to some event, without ever removing them. While it may not look like it, event handlers is a form of list.

Another possible issue is not disposing disposable objects. Such objects may own native memory that need to be explicitly freed. Well designed classes should have a finalizer to ensure the memory is *eventually* freed, but some third party classes are not well designed.

So debugging memory leaks is to a large extent learning how to use a memory debugger effectively. If the leak is of native memory you better hope some managed object owns that memory, otherwise you are are stuck with reviewing code, or using tools specifically designed for native code. If the memory is owned by a managed object, then the process is the same as for any other managed memory leak, just a bit more difficult, since the "total bytes owned" will be incorrect, since the debugger cannot track native memory.